# Can't link wxWidgets app with Code::Blocks / MinGW

Tags: c++, linker, mingw, codeblocks, wxwidgets

I have an already working c++ + wxWidgets app built in Eclipse, with wxWidgets built using MSYS.

Now i'd like to try different IDEs, like CodeLite and Code::Blocks, but when i tried them they did'nt work 'cause i was lacking a build.cfg file they wants.
So i tried a "clean" way, backupped the wxWidgets and build them again using MinGW32-make instead of MSYS.

Trying Code:Block now, i get a lot of "undefined reference" errors, and i can't understand what i've done or set wrong.

I'll try to give here all the related info:

Path to wxWidgets:

```
C:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets
```

Path variable (the related part)

```
PATH=C:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\MinGW\bin;C:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\MinGW\libexec\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1;
```

Mingw v4.8.1, make version

```
C:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets>mingw32-make -v
GNU Make 3.82.90
Built for i686-pc-mingw32
```

wxWidgets build command:

```
C:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\build\msw>mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=debug UNICODE=1 SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=1
```

Code::Block build log:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in MyProject (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -pipe -mthreads -D__GNUWIN32__ -D__WXMSW__ -DwxUSE_UNICODE -Wall -g -D__WXDEBUG__ -IC:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\lib\gcc_lib\mswud -IC:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\include -c C:\Source\Codeblocks\Progetti\MyProject\MyProject\src\CustomControls\TAntiAliasedGauge\TAntiAliasedGauge.cpp -o obj\Debug\src\CustomControls\TAntiAliasedGauge\TAntiAliasedGauge.o
mingw32-g++.exe -pipe -mthreads -D__GNUWIN32__ -D__WXMSW__ -DwxUSE_UNICODE -Wall -g -D__WXDEBUG__ -IC:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\lib\gcc_lib\mswud -IC:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\include -c C:\Source\Codeblocks\Progetti\MyProject\MyProject\src\fMainForm.cpp -o obj\Debug\src\fMainForm.o
mingw32-g++.exe -pipe -mthreads -D__GNUWIN32__ -D__WXMSW__ -DwxUSE_UNICODE -Wall -g -D__WXDEBUG__ -IC:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\lib\gcc_lib\mswud -IC:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\include -c C:\Source\Codeblocks\Progetti\MyProject\MyProject\src\GUI_MainForm.cpp -o obj\Debug\src\GUI_MainForm.o
mingw32-g++.exe -pipe -mthreads -D__GNUWIN32__ -D__WXMSW__ -DwxUSE_UNICODE -Wall -g -D__WXDEBUG__ -IC:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\lib\gcc_lib\mswud -IC:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\include -c C:\Source\Codeblocks\Progetti\MyProject\MyProject\src\My_Project.cpp -o obj\Debug\src\My_Project.o
mingw32-g++.exe -pipe -mthreads -D__GNUWIN32__ -D__WXMSW__ -DwxUSE_UNICODE -Wall -g -D__WXDEBUG__ -IC:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\lib\gcc_lib\mswud -IC:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\include -c C:\Source\Codeblocks\Progetti\MyProject\MyProject\src\Prova_wxcrafter_bitmaps.cpp -o obj\Debug\src\Prova_wxcrafter_bitmaps.o
mingw32-g++.exe -pipe -mthreads -D__GNUWIN32__ -D__WXMSW__ -DwxUSE_UNICODE -Wall -g -D__WXDEBUG__ -IC:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\lib\gcc_lib\mswud -IC:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\include -c C:\Source\Codeblocks\Progetti\MyProject\MyProject\src\Utilities\Utilities.cpp -o obj\Debug\src\Utilities\Utilities.o
C:\Source\Codeblocks\Progetti\MyProject\MyProject\src\Utilities\Utilities.cpp: In function 'char HexToChar(char*)':
C:\Source\Codeblocks\Progetti\MyProject\MyProject\src\Utilities\Utilities.cpp:73:66: warning: operation on 'HexString' may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
  return (char)((AscHex(*HexString++) * 16) | AscHex(*HexString++));
                                                                  ^
C:\Source\Codeblocks\Progetti\MyProject\MyProject\src\Utilities\Utilities.cpp: In function 'byte HexToByte(char*)':
C:\Source\Codeblocks\Progetti\MyProject\MyProject\src\Utilities\Utilities.cpp:77:66: warning: operation on 'HexString' may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
  return (byte)((AscHex(*HexString++) * 16) | AscHex(*HexString++));
                                                                  ^
mingw32-g++.exe -LC:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\lib\gcc_lib -o bin\Debug\MyProject.exe obj\Debug\src\CustomControls\TAntiAliasedGauge\TAntiAliasedGauge.o obj\Debug\src\fMainForm.o obj\Debug\src\GUI_MainForm.o obj\Debug\src\My_Project.o obj\Debug\src\Prova_wxcrafter_bitmaps.o obj\Debug\src\Utilities\Utilities.o  -mthreads  -lwxmsw30ud -lwxpngd -lwxjpegd -lwxtiffd -lwxzlibd -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomctl32 -lwsock32 -lodbc32 -mwindows
C:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\lib\gcc_lib/libwxmsw30ud.a(monolib_xml.o): In function `StartElementHnd':
C:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\build\msw/../../src/xml/xml.cpp:637: undefined reference to `XML_GetCurrentLineNumber'
C:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\lib\gcc_lib/libwxmsw30ud.a(monolib_xml.o): In function `TextHnd':
C:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\build\msw/../../src/xml/xml.cpp:687: undefined reference to `XML_GetCurrentLineNumber'
C:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\lib\gcc_lib/libwxmsw30ud.a(monolib_xml.o): In function `StartCdataHnd':
C:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\build\msw/../../src/xml/xml.cpp:702: undefined reference to `XML_GetCurrentLineNumber'
C:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\lib\gcc_lib/libwxmsw30ud.a(monolib_xml.o): In function `CommentHnd':
C:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\build\msw/../../src/xml/xml.cpp:727: undefined reference to `XML_GetCurrentLineNumber'
C:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\lib\gcc_lib/libwxmsw30ud.a(monolib_xml.o): In function `PIHnd':
C:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\build\msw/../../src/xml/xml.cpp:742: undefined reference to `XML_GetCurrentLineNumber'
C:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\lib\gcc_lib/libwxmsw30ud.a(monolib_xml.o): In function `ZN13wxXmlDocument4LoadER13wxInputStreamRK8wxStringi':
C:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\build\msw/../../src/xml/xml.cpp:813: undefined reference to `XML_ParserCreate'
C:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\build\msw/../../src/xml/xml.cpp:826: undefined reference to `XML_SetUserData'
C:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\build\msw/../../src/xml/xml.cpp:827: undefined reference to `XML_SetElementHandler'
C:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\build\msw/../../src/xml/xml.cpp:828: undefined reference to `XML_SetCharacterDataHandler'
C:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\build\msw/../../src/xml/xml.cpp:829: undefined reference to `XML_SetCdataSectionHandler'
C:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\build\msw/../../src/xml/xml.cpp:830: undefined reference to `XML_SetCommentHandler'
C:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\build\msw/../../src/xml/xml.cpp:831: undefined reference to `XML_SetProcessingInstructionHandler'
C:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\build\msw/../../src/xml/xml.cpp:832: undefined reference to `XML_SetDefaultHandler'
C:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\build\msw/../../src/xml/xml.cpp:833: undefined reference to `XML_SetUnknownEncodingHandler'
C:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\build\msw/../../src/xml/xml.cpp:840: undefined reference to `XML_Parse'
C:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\build\msw/../../src/xml/xml.cpp:843: undefined reference to `XML_GetErrorCode'
C:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\build\msw/../../src/xml/xml.cpp:843: undefined reference to `XML_ErrorString'
C:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\build\msw/../../src/xml/xml.cpp:846: undefined reference to `XML_GetCurrentLineNumber'
C:\SVILUPPO\TOOLS\wxWidgets\build\msw/../../src/xml/xml.cpp:865: undefined reference to `XML_ParserFree'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 29 second(s))
19 error(s), 2 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 29 second(s))
```

I also tried adding other libs i had to add when i built this code under arm-linux) in the linker settings, but these libraries files are not existing (i guess 'cause the MONOLITHIC option):

```
libwxmsw30ud_core.a
libwxmsw30ud_html.a
libwxmsw30ud_adv.a
libwxbase30ud_xml.a
libwxmsw30ud_richtext.a
```

In the end, i don't know what i should to finally link and debug my sources from Code::Block.

Comment: Looks like you need to link your code against libexpat.a (`-lexpat`) as well. Also you should probably heed that undefined behavior warning, it certainly looks undefined to me.

Comment: I don't have that file, if not on this folder:
    C:\SysGCC\BeagleDebian\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\usr\lib\arm-linux-gnueabihf\libexpat.a

I'm on Windows7 / 64, if this matters.



And as we're talking about it: what exactly is the problem of that warning? I don't get it.

Comment: I'm guessing a monolithic build should also build libexpat for you, but for whatever reason isn't. You might want to try asking on wxWidgets support. As for the warning, there's no guaranteed sequence for the expressions on either side of the `|`, your compiler might decide to increment `HexString` on the right hand side, then increment it on the left hand side, the dereference the right and pass it to `AscHex`, then dereference the left etc. etc.

Comment: Found it, the library name is libwxexpatd.a.
If you write it as an answer i'll accept it. And thanks for the explanation of the warning also.

Comment: Looks like you already have an answer from someone more knowledgeable than me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link with `libwxexpat.a` which was created when you built wxWidgets.

Comment: ok :) A question to you and user657257 both, so i can learn a bit: how did you know this? or better; where should i have looked to get this info?

Comment: There is always the brute force way to find out where a symbol is defined: just run `nm -A *.a | fgrep <symbol-name>` (add `-C` option if it's a C++ symbol). In this particular case I didn't have to do it because I know that `XML_xxx()` are expat symbols and I know that we name our expat library `wxexpat` to distinguish it from the (possibly different) system-wide one.